# What is the meaning of the absolute of the Fourier transform in this context?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, signal-processing

In a course talking about Fourrier transform and Nyquist frequency, there is this sentence that I can't understand:

> "If a signal has $|F(w)| \geq  0$ only for frequencies till *f*, than such signal can be sampled at a rate of a least 2*f"

Where f is the frequency of the signal (I guess the "main" frequency...), but what I really don't understand is what $|F(w)|$ stands for... is it the absolute value of the Fourier transform? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform is usually complex and thus multiplied by the conjugate complex to yield the square of the absolute. However, often just the absolute of the Fourier transform is shown, which is real. The square of the absolute has also the property that it describes the power that the signal has within each frequency interval, which is called Parseval's theorem.

The sentence is basically the Nyquist theorem: You need at least two data points per period to reconstruct a signal. So, if your signal has frequencies larger than half the sample rate, these frequencies cannot reconstructed. Actually they would bias your Fourier transform.

If you are interested in these things I can recommend the book "Numerical recipes" from Press et. al.

Comment: I think it's clear thank you, just one thing, when you say "has frequencies larger than" do you mean that the value of the frequency is larger than ? (so for theses freq the signal "oscilate" faster...)

Comment: Basically yes, the signal is a superposition of individual oscillations of different frequencies. The amplitude or power is given by the absolute resp. square of absolute of the Fourier transform, but that works only for those components of the signal that oscillate slower than half the sample rate.

Comment: cool thx, clear now !